# TypeError: 'headers' is an invalid keyword argument for print()

Tags: python-3.x, tabulate

I recently installed tabulate onto conda and I am trying to tabulate my results with print syntax 
Source: [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)
but I am getting "TypeError: 'headers' is an invalid keyword argument for print()"

I have tried "print(tabulate([['Alice', 24], ['Bob', 19]], headers=['Name', 'Age'], tablefmt='orgtbl'))"

```
from tabulate import tabulate
i: int
with open("incre.txt", "w") as file:

    for i in range(1, 100,5):
        mol = int((i*50)/(i+50))
        file.write(str(i)+ " " +str(mol) + "\n")
    print(tabulate([[i], [mol]]), headers=['i' , 'mol'], tablefmt='orgtbl')
    file.close()
```

Expected Results would be on terms of

[image: Expected output example]

I am getting typeerror, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

There is a mistake in the way you wrote your parenthesis, try with that line:

```
print(tabulate([[i], [mol]], headers=['i' , 'mol'], tablefmt='orgtbl'))
```

What you were doing was like doing this:

```
x = tabulate([[i], [mol]]
print(x, headers=['i' , 'mol'], tablefmt='orgtbl')
```

As you can see there, you were trying to call the `print` method with `headers` and `tablefmt` keywords, wich caused the error: `'headers' is an invalid keyword argument for print()`

Update:

I'm not sure, but i think what you try to achieve is:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

values = []

for i in range(1, 100,5):
    mol = int((i*50)/(i+50))
    values.append([i, mol])

print(tabulate(values, headers=['i' , 'mol'], tablefmt='orgtbl'))
```

in your code, you were printing `i` and `mol` after having exited from the while loop, then you would have only printed their last values...